# Reload not working on android with React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am building an react-native app. The tooling for ios works fine.
To develop there i just execute `react-native run-ios` on the command line and i get the ability to reload changes in my app, after i changed the js code.

For android that does not work.

When i run `react-native run-android` and the app is installed on the simulator it seems that a really old js bundle of my app is used. So it seems that the step to build my js bundle is not executed.

When i execute `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` manually the js bundle gets updated and i get the new version of the app, but with this workflow i have to build the whole app everytime i want to see a change.

I also have the build server running on my computer. I start it with `npm start` which starts the following: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`.

The output of this shows me that it is never triggered when using the android simulator. Using the ios simulator it is triggered and it shows my the build progress for the bundle.

So how can i make the android app connect to the build server and reflect my changes in the app?

`React Native Version: 0.55.4
react Version: 16.4.0`

I am happy to provide more info when needed.

Comment: Do you have Metro running ? Does it give you any error ? Also what exactly happens when you press reload on the Android Device in the React Native Toolbar ?

Comment: Metro is running with my `npm start`commando but as stated above not triggered to do anything. Thats the output of the metro bundler:
`Metro Bundler ready. Loading dependency graph, done.`

I cannot reload in the android emulator. I tried to press `Command + M` and also `Command + R` but nothing happened.

Comment: If you stop metro and run ```react-native start``` and after that can you access ```http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false``` ?

Comment: If i try to access `http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false`in the browser i get a 404: `Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots:`. But if i enter `http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false` in the browser i get the js file. I also changed the `jSMainModuleName` in `MainApplication` to `index`. So when i understand that correct that should work.

Comment: What i don't understand is that the android app always tries to load the bundle from the assets. But if i understand correctly it should load the bundle from an url.

Comment: If i copy the resulting file from my bundler to the android assets folder the app launches on android, but then  there is still no refresh with the package server.

Comment: I also noticed that when the app is running on my emulator pressing command + m or command + r nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was now able to fox the problem.

The problem was introduced after renaming the package name of the app.
I probably missed a part in the android app to rename the package.

After using the tool `react-native-rename` everything is working now.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue right now, but even after using this package to rename the Android package it still does not work. Do you know if you did something extra to make it work?